# Java Regex: Find returns true but one of the group() fails to return value

Tags: java, regex

I am having an issue with a regular expression in Java. I tested my Regex and it seems to match fine, but one the groups is returning an empty value. It is able to find the correct number of groups, but I am at loss of words why the second sequence seems to start and end at a wrong index.

Pattern:

```
^http\://[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2}/[\w]{2}/[\w\-]+/(uvw_)+([a-zA-Z0-9]?)+([\w\-]*)$
```

Data to be tested:

```
http://www.testing.ca/en/ABC-DEF/uvw_XY5114_2-Z_1_54321
```

Looking for: `XY5114`

Here is a screenshot from regexplanet:
[image: Test Results here]

Edit: I got this working by using the following pattern:

```
^http\://[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2}/[\w]{2}/[\w\-]+/(uvw_)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([\w\-]*)$
```

And another option suggested:

```
^http\://[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2}/[\w]{2}/[\w\-]+/(uvw_)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\w\-]*)$
```

Comment: Why don't you use `URI` to break your URL into components first, for easier analysis later?

Comment: I would like to do everything using Regex, if possible.

Comment: Well, in this case, regexes are not the best tool

Comment: @Matsemann performance. regexes are O(n) in the length of the string being matched.  In this case, if you don't already have a URL object created from the parts (scheme, host, port, etc.), it's possibly moot.  Extracting elements of a URL object is performed by regex patterns, although it first splits it on standard delimiters, like #, ?, :, etc., to get the strings as short as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "?" in `([a-zA-Z0-9]?)+`. The "?" means it's optional and the "+" means you need at least one, that's kind of a contradiction.

EDIT: You also have to move the "+" inside the group.

This should work:

```
^http\://[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2}/[\w]{2}/[\w\-]+/(uvw_)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\w\-]*)$
```

Comment: Now, it returns just a value "4".

Comment: Thanks, that worked! And another option that I just tried that worked for me was:
^http\://[\w\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2}/[\w]{2}/[\w\-]+/(uvw_)+([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([\w\-]*)$

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that you just want to extract the last section of your URL and split it by underscore? In this case do the following:

```
String url = ....;
int lastSlash = url.lastIndexOf('/');
String[] parts = url.substring(lastSlash + 1).split("_");
```

Comment: I wish to use just a regex pattern to have it taken care of. But Thanks for the suggestion.